# How to do sum of column in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have written the following query to get the name and amount :

```
  select fm.familyname,qt.amount
  from Registrations rs left join Family fm on fm.id = rs.family_id
  left join Quote qt on qt.id = rs.quote_id
  group by  fm.familyname,qt.amount
```

So from the above query i am getting the below answer:

```
name    amount
abc     1200
abc     1300
abc     1400
```

But i want the output like:

```
name    amount
 abc    3900
```

How can i do this? i have used `Sum(isnull(cast(qt.amount as float),0)) as total` but it is doing total of individual column.

How can i get the total ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply `GROUP BY fm.familyname` alone:

```
select fm.familyname, SUM(qt.amount)
from Registrations rs
  left join Family fm on fm.id = rs.family_id
  left join Quote qt on qt.id = rs.quote_id
group by  fm.familyname
```

If you get "Operand data type varchar(max) is invalid for sum operator.", you need to `cast` that column, something like:

```
select fm.familyname, sum(cast(qt.amount as float))
...
```

Comment: it gives error `Operand data type varchar(max) is invalid for sum operator.`

Comment: Is qt.amount a varchar column??? Switch to integer. Until fixed, do cast! (Will edit!)

Comment: Yes . aded that sum line. Thanks

Comment: Only cast will not work, you have to also check if it's number or not and use ISNULL(qt.amount,0) also

Comment: @SandipPatel, like OP wrote in question?

Comment: Yes NULL already checked, but before that also need to check for number

Comment: @SandipPatel. That's why OP really should consider altering the column to a numeric data type!

Answer (score 0):

```
select fm.familyname,
SUM(
    CASE ISNUMeric(LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(qt.amount,'0')))) WHEN 1 THEN CAST(qt.amount as decimal(10,2)) ELSE 0 END
) AS amount
from Registrations rs left join Family fm on fm.id = rs.family_id
left join Quote qt on qt.id = rs.quote_id
group by  fm.familyname
```